# Django gunicorn Nginx setup only showing 404 page

Tags: django, nginx, debian, gunicorn, supervisord

I have setup a Django dev box on a Debian 7 vps following this tutorial

http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2013/06/09/django-nginx-gunicorn-virtualenv-supervisor/

Everything seems to work correctly but when i try to go to my domain my.site i get a 404 error page from nginx.
If i use remote desktop i can see the django project using localhost or 127.0.0.1:8000 or 8001 if i launch gunicorn directly.
I have scoured google and here for multiple solutions but none seem to get rid of my issue?

Allowed hosts is set to domain with and without www.

What would cause this error?
I just want to be able to browse my.site in my browser and view the django project, which doesnt seem to be working

Can someone give me insight on what may be happening!?
Here are my configs

nginx-error.log

```
016/01/11 03:17:51 [error] 29962#0: *5 open() "/webapps/license/static/500.html" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: x.x.x.x, server: my.site, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/webapps/license/run/gunicorn.sock:/", host: "www.my.site"
```

Django

```
(license)app_usr@dev2:~/licdb$ python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 11, 2016 - 19:47:07
Django version 1.9.1, using settings 'licdb.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

Gunicorn start script

```
#!/bin/bash

NAME="licdb"                                  # Name of the application
DJANGODIR=/webapps/license/licdb             # Django project directory
SOCKFILE=/webapps/license/licdb/run/gunicorn.sock  # we will communicte using this unix socket
USER=app_usr                                        # the user to run as
GROUP=webapps                                     # the group to run as
NUM_WORKERS=3                                     # how many worker processes should Gunicorn spawn
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=licdb.settings             # which settings file should Django use
DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE=licdb.wsgi                     # WSGI module name

echo "Starting $NAME as `whoami`"

# Activate the virtual environment

cd $DJANGODIR
source ../bin/activate
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=$DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
export PYTHONPATH=$DJANGODIR:$PYTHONPATH

# Create the run directory if it doesn't exist
RUNDIR=$(dirname $SOCKFILE)
test -d $RUNDIR || mkdir -p $RUNDIR

# Start your Django Unicorn
# Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves (do not use --daemon)
exec ../bin/gunicorn ${DJANGO_WSGI_MODULE}:application \
  --name $NAME \
  --workers $NUM_WORKERS \
  --user=$USER --group=$GROUP \
  --bind=unix:$SOCKFILE \
  --log-level=debug \
  --log-file=-




(license)root@dev2:/webapps/license/bin# ./gunicorn_start
Starting licdb as root
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30278] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  proxy_protocol: False
  worker_connections: 1000
  statsd_host: None
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  post_fork: <function post_fork at 0x1060de8>
  pythonpath: None
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  worker_class: sync
  ssl_version: 3
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  syslog: False
  syslog_facility: user
  when_ready: <function when_ready at 0x1060b18>
  pre_fork: <function pre_fork at 0x1060c80>
  cert_reqs: 0
  preload_app: False
  keepalive: 2
  accesslog: None
  group: 999
  graceful_timeout: 30
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  spew: False
  workers: 3
  proc_name: licdb
  sendfile: None
  pidfile: None
  umask: 0
  on_reload: <function on_reload at 0x10609b0>
  pre_exec: <function pre_exec at 0x1064410>
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  post_worker_init: <function post_worker_init at 0x1060f50>
  limit_request_fields: 100
  on_exit: <function on_exit at 0x1064aa0>
  config: None
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https', 'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on'}
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  pre_request: <function pre_request at 0x1064578>
  post_request: <function post_request at 0x1064668>
  user: 999
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  worker_int: <function worker_int at 0x1064140>
  threads: 1
  max_requests: 0
  limit_request_line: 4094
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  certfile: None
  worker_exit: <function worker_exit at 0x10647d0>
  chdir: /webapps/license/licdb
  paste: None
  default_proc_name: licdb.wsgi:application
  errorlog: -
  loglevel: debug
  logconfig: None
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  syslog_prefix: None
  daemon: False
  ciphers: TLSv1
  on_starting: <function on_starting at 0x1060848>
  worker_abort: <function worker_abort at 0x10642a8>
  bind: ['unix:/webapps/license/licdb/run/gunicorn.sock']
  raw_env: []
  reload: False
  check_config: False
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  nworkers_changed: <function nworkers_changed at 0x1064938>
  timeout: 30
  ca_certs: None
  django_settings: None
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  keyfile: None
  backlog: 2048
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  statsd_prefix:
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30278] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.4.5
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30278] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30278] [INFO] Listening at: unix:/webapps/license/licdb/run/gunicorn.sock (30278)
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30278] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30289] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30289
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30294] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30294
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30295] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 30295
[2016-01-11 03:58:17 +0000] [30278] [DEBUG] 3 workers
```

nginx sites-available

```
upstream license_app_server {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).


  server unix:/webapps/license/run/gunicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;

}


server {

    listen   80;
    server_name my.site;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    access_log /webapps/license/logs/nginx-access.log;
    error_log /webapps/license/logs/nginx-error.log;

    location /static/ {
        alias   /webapps/license/static/;
    }


    location /media/ {
        alias   /webapps/license/media/;

    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        # proxy_buffering off;
        # Try to serve static files from nginx, no point in making an
        # *application* server like Unicorn/Rainbows! serve static files.

        if (!-f $request_filename) {
            proxy_pass http://license_app_server;

            break;

        }

    }


    # Error pages
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /webapps/license/static/;

    }

}
```

Supervisor

```
(license)root@dev2:/etc/nginx# supervisorctl start license
license: started
(license)root@dev2:/etc/nginx# supervisorctl status license
license                          RUNNING    pid 30223, uptime 0:00:19
(license)root@dev2:/etc/nginx#
```

supervisor.conf

```
[program:license]
command = /webapps/license/bin/gunicorn_start                    ; Command to start app
user = app_usr                                                          ; User to run as
stdout_logfile = /webapps/license/logs/gunicorn_supervisor.log   ; Where to write log messages
redirect_stderr = true                                                ; Save stderr in the same log
environment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8nvironment=LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8a
```

Directory structure

```
|-- license
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- admin.py
|   |-- admin.pyc
|   |-- apps.py
|   |-- migrations
|   |   |-- __init__.py
|   |   `-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- models.py
|   |-- models.pyc
|   |-- tests.py
|   `-- views.py
|-- db.sqlite3
|-- licdb
|   |-- __init__.py
|   |-- __init__.pyc
|   |-- settings.py
|   |-- settings.pyc
|   |-- urls.py
|   |-- urls.pyc
|   |-- wsgi.py
|   `-- wsgi.pyc
|-- licdb.tx
|-- manage.py
`-- run
    `-- gunicorn.sock
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Are you able to run the gunicorn bash script yourself without the virtual env being activated ?
2. could you check with a simple nginx config like:

   ```
   server {

      listen 80;

      server_name SITENAME www.SITENAME;


      location /static {

       alias /path/to/your/staticfiles;

      }


       location / {

       proxy_set_header Host $host;

       proxy_pass http://unix:/path/to/your/gunicorn/socket;

      }
   }
   ```

Comment: Yes i can run the gunicorn script and it starts gunicorn no problem, i pasted the command in the gunicorn script block. i can also start it with supervisor. The problem seems to be with the DEBUG = FALSE ALLOWED HOSTS.  If i turn on debug i can access the site, turn off debug and enter my domain it doesnt load the site at all. I have tried entering localhost 127.0.0.1 my domain and the ip of the server nothing will allow the page to display. As a test i added * to allowed hosts to see if it would be accessible but it just shows the 500 error page.

Comment: change the proxy_pass http://license_app_server;
 to proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000; and run the django development server , check if this is working